# Failure to Install Ubuntu 12.04 on USB Flash Drive

Tags: flash

I need Ubuntu on a Flash Drive in order to use Citrix for Linux

I have tried this weekend to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a 16Gb USB flash drive, without apparent success. I have downloaded the ISO image & installed it (repeatedly) using the PenDrive program mentioned on the Ubuntu website.

The PENDRIVE produced has been tested on Fijutsu Siemens & Lenovo laptops - initially with very limited success (I was faced with the Install or try out screen, but only the Install option would be res;ponded to), finally with fatal error messages from both computers - even the 12.04 DVD live image no longer runs now.

I do need the installation this week - please would any Ubuntu experts advise what I am doing wrong? I can't copy the error messages down as they only appear for about a second before being cleared off screen.

All advice very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Use Unetbootin instead. It's fast, easy, and intuitive. Be sure to leave extra memory for the changes you make to your flashdrive. I would not recommend using a flash drive for regular computer use those. Flash drives only have so many reads and writes before they actually just stop working altogether.